# Move every second cell adjacently to the next blank cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

So I am transforming some data and need to move the value inside every second cell adjacently to the right to align the city with the street and the rest of the data:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Loop from the bottom up. You have pseudo-ish-code in your screenshot, have you made an attempt at actually writing it?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: `For lastRow to firstRow Step -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please: It is very fast, uses arrays and works in memory, dropping the processing result at once. Now the two processed columns result is returned in the last sheet empty columns:

```
Sub MoveSecondCellOnNextColumn()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, lastRow As Long
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  Dim lastEmptyCol As Long ' temporarily, until the sub is checked, to drop the processing result
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  lastEmptyCol = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
  ReDim arrFin(1 To Int(UBound(arr, 1) / 2) + 2, 1 To 2)'+ 1 for headers
  
  k = k + 1
  arrFin(k, 1) = "Street": arrFin(k, 2) = "City" 'load column headers
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1 Step 2
     k = k + 1
     arrFin(k, 1) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(k, 2) = arr(i + 1, 1)
  Next i
  
  sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol).Resize(UBound(arrFin, 1), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

After testing and being sure that it does what you need, the last code line must be replaced with:

```
sh.Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.ClearContents
sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 1), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
```

and `lastEmptyCol` will be deleted/commented, not used anymore.

Comment: Thanks, there seems to be a subscript out of range on `arrFin(k, 1) = arr(i, 1)`

Comment: @patriciajlim: What value has `i` when the code stops on error? Moving the cursor over it... Against `lastRow` and `Ubound(arr, 1)`...

Comment: @patriciajlim: And also `k` value...

Comment: @patriciajlim: It is late in my country and I must go to bed... If you will not understand where the problem is, I will help you doing that, but tomorrow. The code works well on my computer. We will see what is about in your case... Did you make any (minor) change in the code?

Comment: i has a value of 81 while k = 42... I pasted the code sample into a new module, but I will try again with another set of data. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try, please replace ` ReDim arrFin(1 To Int(UBound(arr, 1) / 2) + 1,...` with ` ReDim arrFin(1 To Int(UBound(arr, 1) / 2) + 2` and `For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)` with `For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) -1`. Theoretically, `k` shouldn't exceed `Ubound(arrFin)`. I already adapted the answer code, in this way.  It should work now.

Comment: @patriciajlim: Don't you have any feedback?

Comment: Thank you It works :D Selected best answer